# Flurry ads integration using SDK 6.0 creates performance issue app crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, ads, flurry, flurry-analytics

Hi I am using latest flurry SDK 6.0 in app. I need to show ads almost every where in my app. App is `UINavigationControllerBased` contains more `viewController`s. I am using code given [in flurry documentation](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/publisher/code/ios/?utm_source=Ad%20space%20code%20email&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=appspot#sdk-integration-for-ios-6-0-about-the-6-0-0-flurry-sdk).

I am using below code in each and every `ViewController` but some times I move fast just like push and pop before add received,so in that case callbacks are continuously receiving but that viewcontroller is not available in stack at that time app crash or recieve memory. I tried to set `adDelegate` to `nil` in `viewWillDisappear` but flurry documentation says don't set it as `nil`.
Anyone has any ideas regarading this?

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
      [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if(self.adBanner == nil){
            self.adBanner = [[FlurryAdBanner alloc] initWithSpace:@"Flurry Banner"] ;
            self.adBanner.adDelegate = self;
            [self.adBanner fetchAndDisplayAdInView:self.view viewControllerForPresentation:self];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should split the code in two?

Fetch the Ad using `fetchAdForFrame`. This prevents Flurry from using the view you passed.

Then inside the delegate, use `displayAdInView`. Only call this if you know the view is visible. So in `viewWillAppear` set a flag to say visible, in `viewWillDisappear` set a flag to say not visible. This should let you cut off the rendering part.

Seems odd an API like this would have no cancelFetchAd method!